# How to implement CXF WS-Discovery (within a fuse bundle) with WSO2 Governance Registry?

Tags: jboss, wso2, cxf, jbossfuse

I am using **cxf 3.0.4-redhat-***, **Jboss Fuse 6.2.1** and **WSO2 Governance Registry 5.3.0**.

***Scenario:*** I have my WSO2 G-REG up and running. Now I want as my each and every fuse bundle having CXF services (SOAP/REST) should register themselves automatically as soon as they are installed in Fuse and de-register when uninstalled. I used CXF WS-Discovery feature and added a configuration as per [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html). I have done proper steps, debugged the code, Hello/Bye operations are getting invoked whenever I install/uninstall my bundle - but the problem is nothing is happening in WSO2 G-REG side - I mean services are getting visible in WSO2 G-REG.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Does anyone tried and has some updates?